# Redirecting output of list of commands

Tags: bash, grep

I am using grep to pull out lines that match `0.` in multiple files. For files that do not contain `0.`, I want it to output "None" to a file. If it finds matches I want it to output the matches to a file. I have two example files that look like this:

```
$ cat sea.txt 
shrimp  0.352
clam    0.632
$ cat land.txt 
dog 0
cat 0
```

In the example files I would get both lines output from the `sea.txt`, but from the `land.txt` file I would just get "None" using the following code:

```
$ grep "0." sea.txt || echo "None"
```

The double pipe (`||`) can be read as "do foo or else do bar", or "if not foo then bar". It works perfect but the problem I am having is I cannot get it to output either the matches (as it would find in the `sea.txt` file) or "None" (as it would find in the `land.txt` file) to a file. It always prints to the terminal. I have tried the following as well as others without any luck of getting the output saved to a file:

```
grep "0." sea.txt || echo "None" > output.txt
grep "0." sea.txt || echo "None" 2> output.txt
```

Is there a way to get it to save to a file? If not is there anyway I can use the lines printed to the terminal?

Answer (score 6):

You can [group](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping) commands with `{ }`:

```
$ { grep '0\.' sea.txt || echo "None"; } > output.txt
$ cat output.txt
shrimp  0.352
clam    0.632
```

Notice the `;`, which is mandatory before the closing brace.

Also, I've changed your regex to `0\.` because you want to match a literal `.`, and not any character (which the unescaped `.` does). Finally, I've replaced the quotes with single quotes – this has no effect here, but prevents surprises with special characters in longer regexes.

Comment: Nailed it. Thank you for that great answer.

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
echo $(grep "0." sea.txt || echo "None") > output.txt
```

Comment: That would flatten the two lines from `sea.txt` onto one.  You'd have to include double quotes around the `$(…)` to get it to do what's wanted.  There'd also need to be the change in regex outlined in Benjamin's answer.